# Count Function Value from One Sheet to Another Sheet in the Same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, function, count

This seems like it would be relatively simple. I'm trying to take the value/result of the count function for a column in a sheet ("MASTER" in the code below) and have that value display in a range in a separate sheet in the same workbook ("Placement").

The code below works if I have the value display in the same sheet - MASTER to MASTER for instance - but when I try the code below, 0 displays in A1 on "Placement" instead of 30 which is the actual value.

```
Sub countdataincolums()

Dim master, placement
Set master = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
Set placement = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Placement")

placement.Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Count(master.Range("E2:E40"))

End Sub
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into the code window of a workbook with a couple of sheets called "Master" and "Placement" and it worked for me so double-check that the sheets have the right names and you have some numbers in E2:E40 of the master sheet..

Comment: `Dim master As Worksheet, placement As Workseet` Not to solve the problem... Do you have numbers in the column you count? If not, use `CountA`.

Comment: This could be one of those mysteries. Numbers are in the column/rows and "master" and "placement" are correct

Comment: Your code works normal! You have a problem with your data to be processed. If everything asked before is checked, please verify what format do you have in column E:E of "MASTER" worksheet. Try selecting column E:E and then: Data - Text to Columns - Next - Next , choose General and press 'Finish'. You may have a surprise, I hope... Or try using CountA. If is text it will return the number of occurrences.

Comment: Try only changing `Count` with `CountA`. If it will return as you wish, it is clearly a matter of format, even if you can see numbers...

Comment: @Chris Dumas: Still alive...?

Comment: Yes...fascinating. `CountA` worked. The code works perfectly fine now. I'll probably keep 'CountA' instead of trying to re-format the data in the cells, unless I come across another reason why I'd have to change it.

Comment: I also went through and changed the Text to Columns setting and then the `Count` function worked properly. Strange little nuances. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Now I observed the issue about a missing zero decimal. I updated the code in order to solve this issue, too, but according to my understanding about the issue. If you need something else, it would be good to better explain what it is necessary. Giving an example: I would like that the value xxx to be shown as yyy.0w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the next:
The code itself works! Not the most beautiful code, but it should work.

1. Try changing the variable declaration in this way:

   `Dim master As Worksheet, placement As Worksheet`

   This will not solve your problem but it can save you from other troubles...
2. `Count` function counts numbers and `CountA` counts strings. Even if you can see a number in a cell, it is a string for VBA **if its format is** `Text`. So, if you enter any new numbers in that specific column, formatted as `General`, Excel will have a good guess and `Count` function will work well, except the case when the specific column has been formatted like `Text`, using `Text to Columns`. If you want to count everything in that specific range, you can format column E:E as Text, but using `Text to Column` (from Data Tab) and use `CountA`. It will count numbers and strings, too.
3. In order to switch back to `Count` function use, you have to use again `Text to Column` (after the range selection), proceed exactly the same, **but after the second Next, choose General**...
4. Only now I observed your remark a about the missing zero for the first digit. If you would like to see 23 like 23.0, after changing the format in `General`, using `Text to Columns`, format the range like `Custom` and choose ###.0.

Answer (score 1):

@FaneDuru had it figured out...the issue was based on the column formatting:

Try only changing `Count` with `CountA`. If it will return as you wish, it is clearly a matter of format, even if you can see numbers

Changing to `CountA` achieved the desired result and will likely be a durable solution to what I'll need for this particular macro. Reformatting the data via: Data - Text to Columns - Next - Next , choose General and press 'Finish' (per @FaneDuru) and then using `count` also worked, but removed zeros as the first digit, which I need for this particular dataset.

Basically, the `count` function was getting confused. Reformatting did unconfuse `count`, but `counta` provided the desirable result.

If 'counta' no longer produces the desired outcome...I'll be back asking for assistance on how to convert the data so `count` can work and then convert it back.

Thanks again for everyone's assistance!

Comment: It is not the best choice writing an answer in order to ask something else... You must ask for clarifications only in comments! Your question can be closed/deleted, if you do not respect the rules.